# Magento 2: A field shows me duplicate values

Tags: magento2

I have this multiselect field, the data I get from a function and magento internally duplicates me the data at the time of showing them.

[image]

> customer_form.xml

```
     <field name="mod_seasons">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Mod\Seasons\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Group</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">varchar</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">multiselect</item>
                <item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">800</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Seasons</item>
                <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                </item>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

> Mod\Seasons\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Group

```
class Group extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{
    protected $groupCollectionFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Store\Model\ResourceModel\Group\CollectionFactory $groupCollectionFactory
    )
    {
        $this->groupCollectionFactory = $groupCollectionFactory->create();
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return $this->groupCollectionFactory->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```

> InstallData:

```
public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $customerSetup = $this->customerSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $customerSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'mod_seasons');

        $customerSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY,
            'mod_seasons',
            [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => __('Seasons'),
                'input' => 'multiselect',
                'source' => 'Gsp\Seasons\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\Group',
                'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
                'required' => 0,
                'visible' => 1,
                'user_defined' => 0,
                'system' => 0,
                'position' => 800
            ]
        );

        $customerSetup->getEavConfig()->getAttribute(\Magento\Customer\Model\Customer::ENTITY, 'gsp_seasons')
            ->setData('used_in_forms', ['adminhtml_customer'])
            ->save();

    }
```

> UpgradeSchema:

```
public function upgrade(SchemaSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.1.0', '<')) {

            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('store_group'),
                'season_add_days_delivery_date',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Seasons add days to delivery date',
                ]
            );

            $setup->getConnection()->addColumn(
                $setup->getTable('store_group'),
                'season_add_days_delivery_deadline',
                [
                    'type' => \Magento\Framework\DB\Ddl\Table::TYPE_TEXT,
                    'nullable' => true,
                    'comment' => 'Seasons add days to delivery deadline',
                ]
            );
        }
        $setup->endSetup();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
return $this->groupCollectionFactory->toOptionArray();
```

Hi please check
this method is overwrite from
\Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource

Comment: From what I have seen it is not overwritten and the method comes from: \ Magento \ Store \ Model \ ResourceModel \ Group \ CollectionFactory

Answer (score 1):

Are those value and the field created by? If yes then check your installData or updateData script. I think forgot to put

if(version_compare($context->getVersion(), 'x.x.x') < 0)

Comment: These are the different Stores, this method '$this-> groupCollectionFactory-> toOptionArray ()' returns the 3 stores correctly, but when it is displayed, it duplicates them with the same ID. Now I show install and upgrade methods